# By printing "garbage values" in uninitialized data segment (bss) can we map out all values from previous program

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, garbage

I have a weird question, and i am not sure if i will be able to explain it but here we go. While learning C and using it you usually come across the term "trash" or "garbage" value, my first question to that is, is  data left over data in that memory address from some different program or of anything or is it actually some 'random' value , if i take that it is true that is leftover value in that memory address why are we still able to read from such memory address, i mean lets assume we just declare int x; and it is now stored in bss on some memory address #, and we were to output its value we would get the value of that resides on that address, so if all the things i said are true, doesnt that allow for us to declare many many many variables but only declare and not initialize perhaps we can map all the values previously stored in bss from some program from before etc.
I am mostly likely sure that this would be a big security threat and thus i know there is probably some measure against it but i want to know what prevents this?

Comment: The title is nonsense as the BSS segment in *not* uninitialized. Maybe tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: @U.Windl Where i learned about memory management, BSS is called Uninitialized Data Segment.

Comment: BSS is "uninitialized" (in C), but people seem to misunderstand what it means: The BSS segment has just a size, no data (thus "uninitialized"), but it will be filled with zeroes on program start. In old operation systems like MS-DOS where new processes can access old memory contents the runtime library filled the BSS with zeros, while in UNIX-like operating systems the OS only gives out cleared memory to (new) processes. As C "uninitialized" `static` variables are put in BCC, the BCC must be zeroed as C static variables are initialized to zero by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the contents of the `.bss` section are zeroed out before your program starts.  This is to satisfy C's guarantee that global and `static` variables, if not explicitly initialized, will be initialized to zero.

Indeed, on a typical multitasking system, *all* memory allocated by your process will be zeroed by the operating system before you are given access to it.  This is to avoid precisely the security hole you mention.

The values of local (`auto`) variables, on the stack, do typically contain "garbage" if not initialized, but it would be garbage left over from the execution of your own program up to this point.  If your program happens not to have written anything to that particular location on the stack, then it will still contain zero (again on a typical OS); it will never contain memory contents from other programs.

The same goes for memory allocated by `malloc`.  If it is coming straight from the OS, it contains zeros.  If it happens to be a block that was previously allocated and freed, it might contain garbage from your previous use of that memory, or from malloc's internal data, but again it will never contain another program's data.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, clear and concise, upvoted!

Comment: Re “*all* memory allocated by your process will be zeroed”: Uninitialized memory will be cleared (or scrubbed of any sensitive data at least). Memory that is mapped to existing data, such as memory to be loaded from a code segment of an executable file or from some file requested by `mmap` may be simply read from storage without being cleared first.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing *in the C language itself* prevents you from doing almost exactly as you say.  The only thing you said that was wrong, considering only the requirements of C standard, was talking about variables "in bss".  Objects with static storage duration and no initializer (which is the standardese equivalent of variables in bss) are guaranteed to be initialized to zero at program startup, so you cannot access the data of no-longer-running programs that way.  But, in an environment like good old-fashioned MS-DOS or CP/M, there was nothing whatsoever to stop you from setting a pointer to the base of physical RAM, scanning to the end, and finding data from previous programs.

All modern operating systems for full-featured computers, however, provide *memory protection* which means, among other things, that they *guarantee* that no process can read another process's memory, whether or not the other process is still running, except via well-defined APIs that enforce security policy.  The "Spectre" family of hardware bugs are a big deal *just because* they break this guarantee.

The details of how memory protection work are too complex to fit into this answer box, but one of the things that's almost always done is, whenever you allocate more memory from the operating system, that memory is initialized, either to all-bits-zero or to the contents of a file on disk.  Either way you can't get at "garbage".